# How to call an item of array after loading data from csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm pretty new to programming so please bear with me.

I've loaded in data from a csv file using pandas, but when I try to access a specific data point in the list, I get an error.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

allData = pd.read_csv ('ARTestNo1.csv')
trialNumbers = pd.DataFrame(allData, columns= ['Trial Number'])

trialNumbers = trialNumbers.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
x = trialNumbers[3]
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Any help is appreciated!

Edit: The error code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 3

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-36f0a988e42d> in <module>
     13 
     14 trialNumbers = trialNumbers.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
---> 15 x = trialNumbers[3]
     16 
     17 print (Locs)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2978             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2979                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2980             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2981             if is_integer(indexer):
   2982                 indexer = [indexer]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
-> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2900         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 3
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please update with the actual error copied from the repl.

Comment: I would recommend you start by reading through some Pandas documentation such as this helpful page on selecting from dataframes: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: Thank you! The documentation is very helpful